# Unit test or integration test for loading configuration from kubernetes secret using ciris-kubernetes

Tags: scala, unit-testing, kubernetes, configuration, integration-testing

Hello scala community,

I'm using [ciris-kubernetes](https://github.com/ovotech/ciris-kubernetes) to inject credentials and certificates from kubernetes secrets. While it works like a charm, I am wondering what would be the best way to unit test or write an intergration test for this functionality?

More specifically, if one of the primary objectives of **configuration as code** is to write tests for it, shouldn't that aspect be given more importance?

Here's my case class for holding configuration

```
import java.io.File 
import ciris.Secret 

final case class SAMLCertificateConfiguration(publicKey: Secret[File], privateKey: Secret[File], password: Secret[String])
```

and the configuration loader

```
object ConfigurationLoader {

  private[this] val log = LoggerFactory getLogger this.getClass

  private def createConfigurationUsingSecret(namespace: NonEmptyString, secretName: NonEmptyString): IO[SAMLCertificateConfiguration] = {

    def getKubernetesSecret: IO[SecretInNamespace[IO]] =
      for {
        apiClient <- defaultApiClient[IO]
      } yield secretInNamespace[IO](namespace, apiClient)

    def createCertificateConfigurationWith(secret: SecretInNamespace[IO]): IO[SAMLCertificateConfiguration] =
      loadConfig(secret[Secret[File]](secretName.value, "public.crt"), secret[Secret[File]](secretName.value, "private.pfx"), secret[Secret[String]](secretName.value, "password")) {
        (publicKey, privateKey, privateKeyPassword) =>
          SAMLCertificateConfiguration(publicKey, privateKey, privateKeyPassword)
      }.orRaiseThrowable

    for {
      secret <- getKubernetesSecret
      samlCertificateConfiguration <- createCertificateConfigurationWith(secret)
    } yield samlCertificateConfiguration

  }

  def loadSAMLCertificateConfiguration: IO[SAMLCertificateConfiguration] =
    loadConfig(
      envF[IO, ApplicationEnvironment]("APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT")
        .orElse(propF[IO, ApplicationEnvironment]("application.environment"))
        .orNone,
      envF[IO, NonEmptyString]("KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE")
        .orElse(propF[IO, NonEmptyString]("kubernetes.namespace"))
        .orValue("default"),
      envF[IO, NonEmptyString]("KUBERNETES_SECRET_NAME")
        .orElse(propF[IO, NonEmptyString]("kubernetes.secret.name"))
        .orValue("saml-pfx")
    ) { (environment, namespace, secret) =>
      import pp.util.configuration.ApplicationEnvironment._
      log.info(s"Environment: $environment, Kubernetes namespace: $namespace, Kubernetes secret's name: $secret")
      environment match {
        case Some(Test) | Some(Production) =>
          createConfigurationUsingSecret(namespace, secret).unsafeRunSync()
        case _ =>
          createSAMLCertificateConfigurationUsingHOCON
      }
    }.orRaiseThrowable

}

import enumeratum.{Enum, EnumEntry}
import scala.collection.immutable

sealed abstract class ApplicationEnvironment extends EnumEntry

object ApplicationEnvironment extends Enum[ApplicationEnvironment] {
  case object Development extends ApplicationEnvironment
  case object Test extends ApplicationEnvironment
  case object Production extends ApplicationEnvironment
  def values: immutable.IndexedSeq[ApplicationEnvironment] = findValues
}

import ciris._
import lt.dvim.ciris.Hocon._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object DefaultConfigurationLoader {

  def createSAMLCertificateConfigurationUsingHOCON: SAMLCertificateConfiguration = {

    def defaultConfiguration = {
      val fallbackConfiguration = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
                    |saml.certificate {
                    |  privateKey = "/tmp/certificates/private.pfx"
                    |  publicKey = "/tmp/certificates/public.crt"
                    |  password = ""
                    |}
                """.stripMargin)
      ConfigFactory.load().withFallback(fallbackConfiguration)
    }

    def hocon = hoconAt(defaultConfiguration)("saml.certificate")

    loadConfig(hocon[String]("publicKey"), hocon[String]("privateKey"), hocon[String]("password"))((publicKeyPath, privateKeyPath, privateKeyPassword) => {
      import java.nio.file.Paths
      import ciris.Secret
      SAMLCertificateConfiguration(Secret(Paths.get(publicKeyPath).toFile), Secret(Paths.get(privateKeyPath).toFile), Secret(privateKeyPassword))
    }).orThrow()
  }

}
```

Should one use ***io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.server.mock.KubernetesServer*** [as shown over here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/SecretCrudTest.java) and implicitly inject kubernetes java client into the configuration loader, so that it can be mocked in tests?